# My Ubuntu is uber lag

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I had just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my old Sony Vaio laptop. Specs are 
4GB RAM, Core 2 Duo 1.53 Ghz and Geforce 9300m graphics.

I used the Windows installer to install Ubuntu to my laptop  and i'm now using the Unity 2D.

Everything I do is lagging. Using Firefox, or even opening files. The laptop will just randomly lag or freeze. Is there anything that I can do or is it because of the Windows installer? Should I clear out my Windows and use solely Linux?

Or is my graphics or RAM being a problem, as I see some people can still run even only with 2GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check addtional driver tab for drivers, install and test. Read here - [How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/q/47506/35775)

Ubuntu installed via wubi is always slow.

Since the whole ubuntu content is put in packaged format and stored in the hdd, a low speed HDD contributes more slowness to the system.

For using ubuntu you don't need to remove windows. You can perfectly dual boot it, jsut like you are doing with wubi.

If the system is slow, after trying both you can look for a lighter ubuntu based distro like lubuntu or xubuntu. Read more here - [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

For installing ubuntu on a separate partition and dual boot with windows. First uninstall your wubi ubuntu. Defragment your C: drive, and follow this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86KHkeBpsbA

Also There are innumerable tutorial in web to dual boot ubuntu and windows. Just search. If you face any problem, you are welcome here to ask a new question :)

Comment: hi there, i have already had the drivers installed already. you say using ubuntu via wubi will be slow, so do u mean theres a way to use it not via wubi? i had tried to install xubuntu but the speed doesnt seem to be a big difference

Comment: definitely there is another way. Actually `wubi` is the alternate way for the users who don't want to create separate partition for ubuntu. See updated answer

Comment: So i should do the create partition thingy. at least wont be this slow right ?

Comment: then im gonna do it again, maybe the right way. haha

Comment: Just do "along side" option. Installer will do all stuff..

Answer (score 0):

if you are running unity 2d that means you are currently on software rendering mode.. and that's really slowwww and taxing on your cpu. first of all, install ubuntu as dual boot and ensure installation of your GPU drivers so that you can switch to unity 3d. the addtional drivers will help you out here. you can start it by typing additional in unity panel or by typing "jockey-gtk" command in the terminal....

Comment: so using the unity3d will be smoother? i thought the 2d uses less graphics therefore i changed it. i've just removed wubi now im downloading it to boot from usb

Comment: It seems that you might be on gallium LLVMpipe which is a form of sw acceleration. Get the output of command "glxinfo" after you finish your installation and post it here so that i can help you further..

Comment: i dont think i removed wubi the right way already now. when i boot from usb it doesnt show the install alongside windows option. and when i choose the others option. it only let me partition  13gb space while i have about 150gb of free space.

Comment: when i boot, it even shows a previous linux version option. will that be the older one i had?

Comment: Try using EasyBCD in windows 7 to remove the older wubi entry. May be after then ubuntu will detect windows 7. Also make sure that you have uninstalled wubi from Add/Remove programs in windows.